# SDXL Fine Tuning, Zip file not recognized

Tags: github, zip, google-colaboratory

I've been trying to get a Google Colab built for fine tuning SDXL to work, but it has proven to be a headache every step of the way. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AkJ_MWg3gypWTdAJ_6CHJQoH5LdOOOPE

I've gotten it to the point where it will at least given me an error message, but despite Replicate claiming that GitHub pages can be used as the host for Zip files this is what I get back every time, for every version of SDXL tested:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.18/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cog/server/worker.py", line 217, in _predict
result = predict(**payload)
File "train.py", line 142, in train
input_dir = preprocess(
File "/src/preprocess.py", line 58, in preprocess
with ZipFile(str(input_zip_path), "r") as zip_ref:
File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.18/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 1266, in __init__
self._RealGetContents()
File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.18/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 1333, in _RealGetContents
raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

This error message appears with both the Windows default mechanism for creating Zip files, and using 7Zip set to 0 compression.

I also tried to setup an S3 on AWS, but they just kept handing me a 404 error whenever I clicked on S3 from their main menu. Files hosted in Google Colab itself don't work either, and spit out a different error.

Does anyone know a good solution for this?

Comment: Never mind, I resolved this myself. It required copying the "raw" file path from the Github page, reached by: 1) Button: Copy Raw File, 2) copy file path from the downloads page that begins with "https://raw.githubusercontent.com".